# Find if XML contain then return something

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'm trying to find a way where I run a query to check if any xml file contain  something, if true, return me a different tag within that xml. 
Example:

```
<shop>
   <item>
       <Product>shirt</Product>
       <color>red</color>
   </item>
   <item>
       <Product>shirt</Product>
       <color>yellow</color>
   </item>
   <item>
       <Product>jeans</Product>
       <color>blue</color>
   </item>
</shop>
```

assume col name is XML, I can find all cols that has shirts on and I want to get the color of the shirt back

```
[XML].exist ('/shop/item/Product[contains(., "shirt")]') > 0);
```

I want to be able to get a table or an array of just the colors of the shirts back. Is that possible?
I'm using SQL 2012

Comment: What are you expecting for output? And can fix your xml so it is valid?

Comment: Thank you for fixing, I want to get a table or an array with just the colors. Sorry I'm new to db

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shred the XML on `item` elements since there can be more than one `color` we need to select from each XML :

```
SELECT P.I.value('color[1]', 'varchar(100)') AS shirt_color
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY t.[XML].nodes('/shop/item[contains(Product[1], "shirt")]') as P(I)
```

**<kbd>[`rextester demo`](http://rextester.com/PZSZ83488)</kbd>**

Also notice that, by using `CROSS APPLY` and the XPath/XQuery, rows that don't have any "shirt" item would be filtered out, so we no longer need `exist()` in the above.